# How to block .GZ files from IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have the following rules set up in IIS rewrite but the problem is that if the web address is 1998gz it gets blocked.  How do I change the rule so that only pages with the web extension .gz is blocked so that 1998.gz is blocked but not 1998gz.

```
<rule name="Block Zip Request" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*).gz$" />
  <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Test Certificate Info" />
</conditions >  
  <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Comment: To match only a dot, you need to use `\.` to escape.

Comment: Thank you Lex, if I could, I would've marked it as answer.